# Error with Tkinter in Python (v2.7.6) using Cloud9 (c9.io)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I am currently using Python 2.7.6 in Cloud9 to develop a text editor. In order to do that, I am using the Tkinter library, but no matter what code I use, as long as it calls any Tkinter function, I get the following error:

> self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className,
>   interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
>   _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "Text Editor"

This is a sample of a very basic python file I use to test the possible solutions I have come to find, even though none worked:

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk("Text Editor")

root.mainloop()
```

Sorry for not including any more details, but it is the first time I use Tk, and so I have little knowledge about this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like c9.io doesn't support running GUIs remotely, which is not the least bit surprising.